# What is the effect of rpm scriplets returning 1?

Tags: linux, installation, script, uninstall, rpm

According to the RPM documentation, the *%pre*, *%post*, *%preun* and *%postun* scriptlets must return 0 for the (un)installation proceeds.

**(1)** But what is the effect of one of those scriptlets returning a non zero value?

**(2)** Will the operation made so far be undone, leaving the system as it was before invoking the RPM (un)installation?

**(3)** Is the transaction mechanism involved?

I went through the documentation (on many pages including Fedora’s official doc) but I haven’t found any clue (at least nothing 'black-on-white' to my understanding).

Answer (score 1):

The information I have found comes from
[Redhat Bug 216221](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=216221)
from November 2006.
I don't know if the following text is still valid.

The last entry of the post says:

> - %pre and %preun scriptlets exiting with non-zero code cause install/erase to fail just like before. This behavior needs to be
>     preserved as various packages use that to prevent install/uninstall on
>     some conditions.
> - non-zero exit code from other scriptlets is treated as a warning only (ie %postun failing will log a warning but the package will get
>     removed anyway)
> - scriptlets dying on signals and other "abnormal" ways are still treated as errors
> - for all scriptlet errors, RPMCALLBACK_SCRIPT_ERROR notification is issued to the callback, with the tag of the failing script passed in
>     the "amount" parameter and "total" parameter containing RPMRC_OK /
>     RPMRC_FAIL to signal whether rpm treated it as a warning or error

Comment: "This behavior needs to be preserved as various packages use that to prevent install/uninstall on some conditions." is good information. This is from prehistoric age (2006!) but it is, most probably, still valid because the need still exist.

Answer (score 0):

I only have partial answers, but I hope it helps you on the way...

1. the installation will be considered **failed**, but afaik there is no real impact: the files will still be present on your system etc. I have had trouble removing a package where the `%preun` scriptlet failed however.
2. **No operations are undone**. `rpm` cannot magically know how to undo the commands that you put in your scriptlets.
3. I don't really know if the transaction mechanism is involved. You could run some tests for that: installing a good rpm and one with a broken `%post` script...